# Good wordpress sitewide message system plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, message-system

I need a plugin for wordpress that will allow people to put a message at the top of the site that may state things like upcomming events or notifications of outages of our server..etc...etc..
Anyone know of a plugin that can do this?

All the one's I've found like WP Announcement and Announcer don't seem to handle this very well. I cannot have the modal popup either.

Comment: You running 3.0? If so, add a custom post type `notification`, then use a custom query to pull in the latest X notifications in your theme files. Can post code if you want?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a roll your own version. Using a plugin framework, like [PodsCMS](http://www.podscms.org/) can help with this and even make it manageable with custom admin menus. This combined with the [Adminimize](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/) plugin can even help with restricting access to this feature on a user role basis.

Comment: Kind of looking for something with like time/date based messages displaying on the site home page. I don't want to add PodsCMS and Adminimize just to create a single feature.

Comment: This can be used for the simple, single feature and it can be used to create a time/date based solution. It's all in how you write your PHP.